# securing a Google Apps Script linked to an authorized trigger so others can edit

Tags: security, google-apps-script, google-authentication, privacy, google-apps-script-editor

I am pretty sure my understanding is correct but since I cannot find any Google documentation that explicitly highlights this I wanted to ask here.

Per https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable:

> Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who created them.

And we know that when you create a trigger it will ask to authorize for all the scopes the script uses.

Then, that means that anyone with edit access to the script could leverage the Google identity of the user used to create the trigger to access the scopes the trigger is authorized for.

For example:

- User 1 creates a Google Apps Script that uses [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) to send an e-mail
  (i.e. `GmailApp.sendEmail("one@example.com", "test subject", "email body");`)
- User 1 creates a trigger to run said script every hour and authorizes it with the appropriate GmailApp scopes
- User 1 gives User 2 **edit** access to said script

Now, User 2 can go into said script and make changes to the code and access User 1's Gmail account. For example, user 2 could change the code to:

```
var emails = GmailApp.search("search string to find sensitive emails")
// use GmailApp.sendEmail to forward those details to someone else like User 2
```

All they would have to do is make changes to the code and save; they wouldn't need to re-create the trigger since it already exists. And the next time the trigger runs it would run the newer/updated code.

I was able to confirm this behavior by creating a test script on one of my accounts and giving another account edit access.

So my question is, what is the official/recommended way to mitigate this risk? The obvious answer is to not give anyone else edit access but what if that is not an option -- what if for support purposes multiple people need to be able to access the script, then what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, the only official/recommend way is to limit editing access to **trusted** persons.

In your particular example, User 1 could have chosen MailApp instead of GmailApp.  The two seemingly redundant services are available separately because MailApp has very limited privledges exposed compared to GmailApp.  (For instance, User 2 cannot search the victims Gmail with the MailApp service.)

You can collaborate while avoiding giving direct access to your script file using `clasp` and `git`.   Only you push with `clasp` to the script.  Everyone else submits changes through `git`.  You can setup the system to be fully automatic (i.e. a `git push` triggers a `clasp push`) or manual (i.e. you review all changes first), bit either way you have good records of who did what, when with `git`.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into clasp.

Comment: I got `clasp` working on Windows 10. And I have `git`. How would I make it so when someone else pushes changes through `git` it automatically updates through `clasp`? I'm not seeing some built in way and not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan research "git hooks" - it's a vast subject well beyond the scope of what I can say in these comments, but well documented and there's surely many examples on Stack Overflow.  Specifically you'll probably want a server-side hook that will run `clasp push` if you allow it.  It won't be trivial to setup.

Comment: Doh! Brain fart. I know of `git hooks` but didn't connect the dots. I was thinking it was something on `clasp` side. Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There's inherent *trust* when you provide edit access to the script project. You either trust the person or don't trust them. There's no inbetween.

Some "theoretical" ways you may still protect the data:

- Create and use different Google accounts.
- Install Triggers at the specific deployment/not at `Head`:

  - Possible only if done manually. Installable triggers created programmatically can only be used at `Head`
  - When you deploy a web-app/api, You can deploy it a specific version.
  - This deployment version can then be provided, When you create a new trigger for a project [here](https://script.google.com/home/).
  - There is no need for a working web-app/api. We're only looking to get a deployment id.
  - In this way, even if user changes the script, your trigger will only run at the old version deployed.
  - Deployed versions can be seen at Publish> Deploy from manifest.
- As the previous answer states, `git` would be a better call.

For all practical purposes, any data you share with a malicious entity should be  considered compromised.

Comment: Just cause you trust someone to edit code does not mean you trust them to have access to your Google stuff like Gmail and Drive. Using `Head` won't work cause the goal is for a 2nd person to be able to make changes if needed. So that person would need to be able to make changes and have it go live. `Git` has the same problem because the trigger owner would still have to push the updated code. The idea is for a 2nd person to be able to edit the code if the primary is not available without the 2nd person getting access to the primary's Google identity.

Comment: @IMT *Just cause you trust someone to edit code does not mean you trust them to have access to your Google stuff like Gmail and Drive* Yes, it does.Code acts as you and accesses your gmail and drive to do some stuff impersonating you. If someone has access to your code, they have, by definition, access to all that the code has access to.The idea here is not to use *Head*,so that after the user2 edits the code, you'll still need to authorize that new version and manually accept it. *Sothat person.. need to be able to make changes and have it go live.* You want it to go live and avoid exposure?!

Comment: Code doesn't act as me. The trigger acts as me. Just cause I want someone to be able to edit code does not mean I want them to be able to act as me by way of the trigger. Google's official solution is to use a different Google account. And its a valid proposal that makes good sense. I just need to convince our security team to allow it. But its also an obviousness risk. I wonder how many orgs are using G-Suite and employees have unknowingly given someone else access to their Gmail because they gave edit access to code that is tied to an authenticated trigger.

Comment: @IMT *The trigger acts as me*. The trigger acts as you only on the code you specified when you set up the trigger. Can we say then, the trigger transfers your "me" to the code? Then the code acts as you to do stuff on your behalf? Just curious, what's  your expected solution here?

Comment: If I auth trigger to send email to you@example.com from me@example.com, I want someone to be able to edit code but not change it to send email to them@example.com from me@example.com. It's about restricting what they can do with the trigger. I am looking for a way to have someone edit code without being able to gain access to my Google identity. A secondary Google account is a good solution. Using a service ID is another solution. My company does not allow either which is why I was looking for an alternative. But I think this is a case where company has to bite the bullet. Working on it.

Comment: @IMT So, you're looking for granular/fine permission control?  Permission only to send to whitelisted recipients. But  powdering down permissions to such  granular level would be nightmare for Google and developers `MailApp` restricts permission to  your inbox, but don't think that's what you're after. *I am looking for a way to have someone edit code without being able to gain access to my Google identity*  Like I said, the code assumes your identity. Giving someone access to your code/project means they assume your identity too.The oauth screen will say Allow this app to "Send email as you"?

Comment: @IMT When you click ok, the app gains all permissions to act as you. If you provide a way to edit that app, that editor may go rogue and act evil. That's why there are git control systems/version control. Merge changes or reject PRs... Someone needs to monitor that the code is ok before deploying.

Comment: Yeah. I think what I'm after is not feasible. Using a second account and/or a service ID is the best approach. But I do think Google could be scarier with the warning when giving someone else edit access to your code. Maybe some kind of special warning if you give edit access to a code tied to a trigger. It it implied implicitly but I think considering the user-base it needs to be more explicit.

Comment: @IMT I agree with the scary warning.

Comment: I discovered something interesting (to me). When you deploy a version and create a trigger against it, if you, or anyone else who has edit access to the code/project, saves a new version and deploys it, the trigger YOU created will **automatically** be updated to use the new deployed version.