# How to upload files to drive in Google-script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that lets you choose a file from your drive into my app. i want to be able to pick a file from the computer not from a drive, is this possible? Maybe some kind of htmlservice that will do this, but i can't figure out how to get the blob out of it to upload.

EDIT:

to include what has been proposed in comments. With the following code i do get the file uploaded into the wanted folder, but it hangs in "Uploading. Please wait..." even though it is already uploaded.

Code.gs

```
function showPicker() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('FileSelect.html')
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(200)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a file');
}

function uploadTheFile(theForm) {
  Logger.log("TEST");
  Logger.log(theForm);
  var fileBlob=theForm.fileToLoad;
  Logger.log(fileBlob);
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById('1dUfcChYwwSX3NLIEGg7g5MetpXfqu_pz');
  var file=fldr.createFile(fileBlob);
  var fi=formatFileName(file);
  var fileInfo={'name':fi.getName(),'type':fileBlob.getContentType(), 'size':fileBlob.getBytes(), 'folder':fldr.getName()};
  return fileInfo;
}
```

FileSelect.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  function fileUploadJs(frmData) {
    document.getElementById('status').style.display ='inline';
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
      .uploadTheFile(frmData)
  }

  function updateOutput(info)  {
    var br='<br />';
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('status');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = br + 'File Upload Successful.' + br + 'File Name: ' + info.name + br + 'Content Type: ' + info.type + br + 'Folder Name: ' + info.folder;
  }

  console.log('My Code');
</script>
<style>
  body {background-color:#ffffff;}
  input{padding:2px;margin:2px;}
</style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="formDiv">
      <form id="myForm">
        <input name="fileToLoad" type="file" /><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="fileUploadJs(this.parentNode)" />
      </form>
    </div>
  <div id="status" style="display: none">
  <!-- div will be filled with innerHTML after form submission. -->
  Uploading. Please wait...
  </div>  
  <div id="controls">
      <input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57581534/7215091

Comment: Hello pato.llaguno, did @Cooper's link solve your issue? If not, what else do you expect to achieve and/or what type of issues are you running into? Cheers!

Comment: @Cooper Thanks! I am able to use that script to uplaod the file, but i don't know if im doing something wrong. i am outputting the html like this. SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a file') and it works, but has no format the html. On the other side, it does go to the selected folder but for some reason the response does not come back so that it changed the text to finish uploading. im i doing something wrong?

Comment: @ale13 just commented on it.

Comment: is formatFileName needed? I thought it was an included function, its one done by you right? what does that do?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the solution to work as desired, I suggest you make the following changes in the code you provided:

1. remove the `var fi=formatFileName(file);` from the `uploadTheFile()` function, as the `formatFileName()` method does not exist and it is not needed;
2. update the `var fileInfo` to this:

```
var fileInfo={'name':file.getName(),'type':fileBlob.getContentType(), 'size':fileBlob.getBytes(), 'folder':fldr.getName()};
```

So basically instead of using the `formatFileName()` you will just use directly the `file.getName()` for retrieving the name of the file.

Moreover, here are a few links that might help you:

1. [HtmlService Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service);
2. [Apps Script Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).