# Uploading a file using an HtmlService form in Google Apps always causes "server error" and a stack trace

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, file-upload, web-applications, v8

I am trying to make a script for my Google spreadsheet in which I upload an XML file and process its data. I am able to create a form, display it in a modal dialog, but I get a strange error when I attempt to submit a form with a file: Nothing is logged for the error in Stackdriver Error Reporting. However, the web browser console logs the following error message:

```
Error: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.
```

The error message comes with a stack trace:

```
Zd https://n-z7hx4jjtvixobmaqkddve7tkcdyndjsnh3plmfq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/static/macros/client/js/2745927008-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__en_gb.js:56
    bf https://n-z7hx4jjtvixobmaqkddve7tkcdyndjsnh3plmfq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/static/macros/client/js/2745927008-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__en_gb.js:71
    G https://n-z7hx4jjtvixobmaqkddve7tkcdyndjsnh3plmfq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/static/macros/client/js/2745927008-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__en_gb.js:15
    J https://n-z7hx4jjtvixobmaqkddve7tkcdyndjsnh3plmfq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/static/macros/client/js/2745927008-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__en_gb.js:99
    Id https://n-z7hx4jjtvixobmaqkddve7tkcdyndjsnh3plmfq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/static/macros/client/js/2745927008-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__en_gb.js:47
    Ed https://n-z7hx4jjtvixobmaqkddve7tkcdyndjsnh3plmfq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/static/macros/client/js/2745927008-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__en_gb.js:48
    b https://n-z7hx4jjtvixobmaqkddve7tkcdyndjsnh3plmfq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/static/macros/client/js/2745927008-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__en_gb.js:44
```

Of course, the stack trace doesn't help here, as it points to a huge minified JavaScript file on Google's servers.

I have tried replicating the examples in the current Google Apps documentation as well as a few old and recent examples I could find on StackOverflow, and the issue is always the same: When comes the time to submit the form data, the script crashes.

I know that this is specifically caused by the file input field. If I remove it, I'm able to submit the form and process its data. If I add the file input field, I get the error as soon as I submit the form.

I can tell the issue is not the file. I have tried uploading a big (125 kb) text file at first, followed by one a few bytes in size, and even not submitting any file at all, and I get the same error. I'm encountering this issue on both Chrome and Firefox, on two separate Google accounts.

Here is my Google script. The `updateTracker` method is called when clicking on a drawing object that I placed in the spreadhseet.

```js
function updateTracker()
{  
  var thisUI = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var htmlUpdatePage = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('myPage');
  var updatePrompt = thisUI.showModalDialog(htmlUpdatePage, 'Update');
}

function digestXml(theForm) {
  //var fileBlob = theForm.xmlFile;
  var thisUI = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  thisUI.alert("Test");
}
```

Here is my HTML file, "myPage":

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      // Prevent forms from submitting.
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);     

      function submitXml(objForm)
      {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateUrl).digestXml(objForm);
      }
      function updateUrl(url) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = 'Got it!';
      }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="xmlForm" onsubmit="submitXml(this)">    
      <input type="file" value="Browse" name="xmlFile" />
      <input type="submit" value="Digest" />
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can tell that the issue occurs precisely when trying to pass `objForm` from the HTML to the Google Script. I'm able to write to the console right before the line `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateUrl).digestXml(objForm);` in HTML, but I don't get to `thisUI.alert("Test");` in the Google Script. If I remove the parameter `objForm` from `digestXml()` in the HTML, the crash does not occur.

Comment: How long  has the issue been?  You should open a issue at issuetracker. See apps script tag info page for details.

Comment: Here's a file upload example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57581534/7215091

Comment: I tried your code and did not get the same error - I assume it must be related to your file. Did you try with another file?

Comment: @Cooper This gives me the same result. However, I notice that in the asker's example, he uses this method: function doGet() { return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index'); }. This does not work for me. It causes a "server error" just as soon as I run doGet(), except this one does not have a stack trace. Perhaps I'm missing something in the steps leading up to displaying the form?

Comment: @ziganotschka I tried many different files. Just to make sure: In what context and what did you to call the updateTracker function? Maybe the steps leading up to it are the problem.

Comment: I simply an it from the script editor. And the I chose a file and pressed "Submit". Are you running the function from the script editor, or is it assigned to a button / called from another function?

Comment: @ziganotschka If I try to run updateTracker from the script editor, nothing happens. Because of that, I just presumed it was impossible to test UI features from the script editor. Therefore, I am always testing my function by linking it to a drawing object that I added to my Google sheet and clicking on it. Is there something missing with my process?

Comment: @TheMaster I've tried this on a new Google sheet on my other Google account. No dice.

Comment: Does your drive have enough space?

Comment: @TheMaster Yep. I've tried this with files that are just a few bytes in size.

Comment: Change `thisUI.alert("Test");` to `console.log("Client called on"+ new Date());return "woohoo";` and check view> stackdriver log and error reporting. Also use ``/dev`` url  to check

Comment: @TheMaster It appears that the issue occurs in Google's latest version of their app scripting interface, V8, but if I switch to STABLE, it does not occur. I added this information as an answer.

Comment: @ziganotschka  It appears that the issue occurs in Google's latest version of their app scripting interface, V8, but if I switch to STABLE, it does not occur. However, all my new scripts are configured to use V8 by default. Does that not happen to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the issue only occurs in a recently released version of Google App's scripting interface, "V8".

When I create a script, I am prompted to use this version of their scripting interface. Trusting Google to test their functionalities, I accepted without thinking.

If I edit my script's configuration file to use STABLE instead of V8, I do not encounter the issue. If you're having this issue, here's how to do that:

1. Open the Script Editor.
2. In the top menu, select View > Show manifest file.
3. In the files list, open `appsscript.json`.
4. Replace `"runtimeVersion": "V8"` with `"runtimeVersion": "STABLE"`
5. Save.

This is however alarming as I presume the current stable version will be deprecated eventually in favor of V8. I logged an issue for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149980602