# Google app script: upload a csv file from html service

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a csv file from an html service in google sheets, and after some research I found some code which seemed to be working at the time:

**html service call**:

```
function importAnalysis() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Import')
      .setWidth(1524)
      .setHeight(800);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Import d\'analyse');
}
```

**html template**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <form>
        <input type="file" name="analysisCsv" accept=".csv">
        <input type="button" onclick="google.script.run.processForm(this.parentNode);">
      </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**gs file** (I commented further code to isolate the source of the problem):

```
function processForm(form) {
  let fileBlob=form.analysisCsv;
//  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Table_Analysis");
//  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
//  let values = []
//  let rows = fileBlob.contents.split('\n');
//  for(let r=0; r<rows.length; ++r){
//    values.push( rows[r].split(';') );
//  }
//  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
//    sheet.getRange(lastRow+i+1, 1, 1, values[i].length).setValues(new Array(values[i]));
//  }  
}
```

Problem is I get an error 400 on processForm function:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()"

Do you know what's wrong with my code, or another way to upload csv content in my sheet?

Comment: Could you try renaming the function name to something like `receiveForm`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading a file using an HtmlService form in Google Apps always causes "server error" and a stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60331688/uploading-a-file-using-an-htmlservice-form-in-google-apps-always-causes-server)

Comment: Try using something like google.script.run.proccessForm(this.parentNode)

Comment: Could you please try to use the STABLE version of Apps Script instead of V8 just in case that is the problem and let me know how did it go with that? To achieve this follow these steps: ```Open the Script Editor.
In the top menu, select View > Show manifest file.
In the files list, open appsscript.json.
Replace "runtimeVersion": "V8" with "runtimeVersion": "STABLE"
Save.```

Comment: When I change "V8" for "STABLE", I get an error "Missing ; sign before instruction" and  I can't track where it comes from, html doesn't show at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to sum it up, I had to force Legacy runtime:
Select Run > Disable new Apps Script runtime powered by V8.
Then edit all the V8 syntax:replace "let" by "var" mainly.
Now it's working, thanks to all.

See 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime

Answer (score 0):

You can't provide doPost() with a parameter.  From the documentation:

`When a user visits an app or a program sends the app an HTTP GET request, Apps Script runs the function doGet(e). When a program sends the app an HTTP POST request, Apps Script runs doPost(e) instead. In both cases, the e argument represents an event parameter that can contain information about any request parameters. The structure of the event object is shown in the table below:`
And [here's a link to that](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)

As I stated in my comment above a simple way of passing a form to the server is:

`google.script.run.proccessForm(this.parentNode)`

And this is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) and partly [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode)

**Well I finally ran your code myself and sure enough it's not working in V8.**

So I moved to the old version and this is the code I used:

GS:

```
function runThree() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah3').setWidth(400).setHeight(400);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Title');
}

function processForm(form) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(form));
  var fileBlob=form.analysisCsv;
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(getGlobal('TestFolderId'));
  var file=folder.createFile(fileBlob);
  var csv=Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet10");
  var rg=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,csv.length,csv[0].length).setValues(csv);
  return "I've got it";
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form>
        <input type="file" name="analysisCsv" accept=".csv">
        <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="intermediate(this.parentNode);">
        <div id="msg"></div>
      </form>
      <script>
        function intermediate(obj) {
          google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(function(msg){$('#msg').html(msg);google.script.host.close();})
          .processForm(obj);
        }
        console.log('My Code');
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

I just created a csv file and upload to a folder and then using [Utilites.parseCsv()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parseCsv(String)) which converts it to a 2D array that can be inserted into a spreadsheet with setValues();

Comment: Thank you, I changed the function name but the error is still there.

Comment: Here's an example you can take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57581534/7215091

Comment: It's basically the same code, except the server function is called in script instead of body. I tried it but still got the same error.

Comment: Just curious but why did you comment out your code?

Comment: I just wanted to be sure the error wasn't caused by further code, but it happens on line 1 (function call).

Comment: Well I actually ran the code finally and in V8 it's not working but in Rhino it's working.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to run it in Legacy but it shows a "missing ;" error, I'm still trying to find where it comes from.

Comment: All right I had to get rid of V8 syntax (let, for in...), now it's working in Legacy!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using **client-side [`FileReader`](https://web.dev/read-files) API**:

`code.gs`:

```js
function doSomething(csvstr) {
  Logger.log('doSomething', csvstr);

  const csvarr = Utilities.parseCsv(csvstr);

  return csvarr; // now an array !
}
```

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file">

    <script>
    const $input = document.querySelector('input')

    $input.onchange = function (e) {
      // File
      const file = e.target.files[0]

      //
      // FileReader
      //
      // see: https://web.dev/read-files/#read-content
      //

      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onerror = event => {
        console.error('error while reading CSV file', event)
        reader.abort()
      }

      reader.onload = event => {
        const content = event.target.result // result
        console.log(content)

        // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run
        google.script.run
          .withFailureHandler(err => {
            console.error('oh noes', err)
          })
          .withSuccessHandler(val => {
            console.log('yay!', val)

            google.script.host.close() // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host#close
          })
          .doSomething(content)
      }
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```